# Windows Forms DataGridView - Custom Cell to view Age based on Birthdate

Tags: c#, winforms

**The problem:**

To display an **age** column based on **birthdate** data-bound value inside a DataGridView.

**What I have done:**

I designed the following user control for age column (I did not provide the code of the user control as it is long)

[image]

**What I am struggling with is:**

How can I host this user control inside the DataGridView just for viewing (No editing)

Comment: Please mention me in case you need the AgeControl Code!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom DataGridViewTextBoxCell type and bind it to the birth date field. Then you can display each piece of the age in different labels inside that cell or paint it. Learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/customize-cells-and-columns-in-the-datagrid-by-extending-behavior).